# Looking for a Harry Potter fic with magically powerful, platonic Harry & Voldemort

Tags: story-identification, harry-potter, fan-fiction

I read it several years ago, though I can’t remember on which fanfic site it was. I think it was a trilogy and I remember it being complete.

It was 6th or 7th year, and Harry was some kind of semi-prisoner of Voldemort (who was actually sane and an effective dark lord)? It wasn’t Dark Harry or any kind of character bashing. I remember thinking I loved its portrayal of the war and its realism.

Harry was also an animagus (a falcon or an eagle) and learned fencing or sword fighting in one of the Malfoy tents (they were like, on castle grounds or in the forest or some kind of war-camp-like area???).

I remember some kind of mind or magic meld scene at some point, and that Harry eventually killed Voldemort and won, later becoming a DADA teacher. But that also, Voldemort continued haunting him as a ghost (which no one believed at first), and actually helped him run some of his DADA classes. In the end, Voldemort tries tricking Harry and there’s some kind of happy resolution but I don’t remember what exactly occurs.

Anyone know what fic I’m remembering?